# How to check completeness of a statistic of a continuous variable?

Tags: statistics, measure-theory, statistical-inference

I have come across some problems of the form:

> Given $X=(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ independent random variables with distribution in a parametric family $\{ F_\theta : \theta \in \Theta \}$, with density
>   $f_\theta(x)$, defined in an interval dependent on $\theta$ (the expression for $f_\theta(x)$ is given), find a statistic that is sufficient and complete
>   for $\theta$.

The standard procedure in these is to use Neyman-Fisher's factorization theorem to find a sufficient statistic, and prove it is also complete. So let $T$ be this statistic, and $f_\theta^T(t)$ its density.

Remember:

> $T$ is *complete* if, for all $h: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$ measurable,
>   $$E_\theta[h\circ T \circ X] = 0 \quad \forall \theta\in\Theta \implies h = 0\quad P_\theta\text{-a.s.}\quad \forall \theta\in\Theta$$

Then, for $h$ measurable, this a typical case: $$E_\theta[h\circ T \circ X] = \int_{-\infty}^\theta h(t)f_\theta^T(t)dt = 0 \quad \forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}$$

Now, everywhere I've seen this solved, it is claimed that $h = 0$ by the FTC (differentiating both sides with respect to $\theta$), but $h$ need not be continuous, only measurable. My question is, is this argument correct? In affirmative case, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This step can be justified by [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem).